# ActiveSupport Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm taking over an existing project of Ruby on Rails, and I have this kind of stuff displayed on the website:

```
--- !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
controller: static_pages
action: home
```

This is displayed on every page, and I'd like to remove this.

Any bit of help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look for this in your application.html.erb :

```
<%= debug(params) if Rails.env.development? %> or <%= debug(params) %>
```

That's the code that display all these information and remove it if needed, but it may only be displayed in development environment if the condition is present.

Answer (score 0):

Your predecessor has put some code in a view file, by the sounds of it either a layout or a partial that is loaded by a layout, which renders the information out.  It's not standard rails behaviour.  You can look for it with this command line snippet (run in your rails folder)

```
find app/views  -print | awk '{print "\""$0"\""}' |xargs grep -n "controller:"
```